Airflow timetable implementation issue
I'm trying to create custom schedule for airflow DAG via timetable. Just for test I implemented https://www.astronomer.io/docs/learn/scheduling-in-airflow#timetables full code is below.
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from typing import Optional

from airflow.decorators import dag

from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from pendulum import Date, DateTime, Time, timezone, duration

from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from airflow.timetables.base import DagRunInfo, DataInterval, TimeRestriction, Timetable

UTC = timezone("UTC")

class UnevenIntervalsTimetable(Timetable):

    def infer_manual_data_interval(self, run_after: DateTime) -> DataInterval:
        delta = timedelta(days=1)
        # If time is between 6:00 and 16:30, period ends at 6am and starts at 16:30 previous day
        if run_after >= run_after.set(hour=6, minute=0) and run_after <= run_after.set(hour=16, minute=30):
            start = (run_after-delta).set(hour=16, minute=30, second=0).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
            end = run_after.set(hour=6, minute=0, second=0).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
        # If time is after 16:30 but before midnight, period is between 6:00 and 16:30 the same day
        elif run_after >= run_after.set(hour=16, minute=30) and run_after.hour <= 23:
            start = run_after.set(hour=6, minute=0, second=0).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
            end = run_after.set(hour=16, minute=30, second=0).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
        # If time is after midnight but before 6:00, period is between 6:00 and 16:30 the previous day
        else:
            start = (run_after-delta).set(hour=6, minute=0).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
            end = (run_after-delta).set(hour=16, minute=30).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
        return DataInterval(start=start, end=end)

    def next_dagrun_info(
        self,
        *,
        last_automated_data_interval: Optional[DataInterval],
        restriction: TimeRestriction,
    ) -> Optional[DagRunInfo]:
        if last_automated_data_interval is not None:  # There was a previous run on the regular schedule.
            last_start = last_automated_data_interval.start
            delta = timedelta(days=1)
            if last_start.hour == 6: # If previous period started at 6:00, next period will start at 16:30 and end at 6:00 following day
                next_start = last_start.set(hour=16, minute=30).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
                next_end = (last_start+delta).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
            else: # If previous period started at 14:30, next period will start at 6:00 next day and end at 14:30
                next_start = (last_start+delta).set(hour=6, minute=0).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
                next_end = (last_start+delta).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
        else:  # This is the first ever run on the regular schedule. First data interval will always start at 6:00 and end at 16:30
            next_start = restriction.earliest
            if next_start is None:  # No start_date. Don't schedule.
                return None
            if not restriction.catchup: # If the DAG has catchup=False, today is the earliest to consider.
                next_start = max(next_start, DateTime.combine(Date.today(), Time.min).replace(tzinfo=UTC))
            next_start = next_start.set(hour=6, minute=0).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
            next_end = next_start.set(hour=16, minute=30).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
        if restriction.latest is not None and next_start > restriction.latest:
            return None  # Over the DAG's scheduled end; don't schedule.
        return DagRunInfo.interval(start=next_start, end=next_end)


class UnevenIntervalsTimetablePlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "uneven_intervals_timetable_plugin"
    timetables = [UnevenIntervalsTimetable]


@dag(
    dag_id="example_timetable_dag_2",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 10, 9),
    max_active_runs=1,
    schedule=UnevenIntervalsTimetable(),
    default_args={
        "retries": 1,
        "retry_delay": duration(minutes=3),
    },
    catchup=True
)
def generate_dag():
    EmptyOperator(task_id="task")

I got error when I checked Airflow web UI
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/bigquery_to_ch_events_loading/schedule2.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/inspect.py", line 3052, in bind_partial
    return self._bind(args, kwargs, partial=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/inspect.py", line 3034, in _bind
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: got an unexpected keyword argument 'schedule'

What can be issue ? I'm not so experienced in python. Is it probably because of Airflow version and some difference in TimeTable class. Airflow version 2.3.4

The schedule param was introduced in Airflow 2.4.0. In Airflow 2.3.4, schedule_interval was used instead of schedule.
